# Why does MPIEXEC (MPICH2) launch more slowly in windows 8 than windows 7

Tags: mpich

With MPICH2, I have observed (both by watching Task Manager and also just experiencing a noticeable delay in the case of Windows 8) that with 8 processes the launch of all the processes on a Windows 7 machine seems to be almost simultaneous and immediate after the mpixexec command is issued, while there is a noticeable delay between process launches (about 0.5 sec) with Windows 8, and with Windows 8 there is a noticeable overall delay of a few seconds between issuing the mpiexec command and the actual appearance of the initial results on the console (which in the program is almost immediate).  I have seen this on a variety of my own machines, and also some colleagues who run the same program have seen the same issue. Is this is known issue and/or is there some thing that can be done to reduce or eliminate the problem?  (Specific command issued is "mpiexec -channel shm -n 8 -localonly prog.exe")

Comment: Which version of MPICH are you using? The last version that supported Windows is 1.4.1p and it's quite old at this point. You might be better served to switch to an MPI implementation that actually supports Windows, such as MS-MPI (free): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb524831(v=vs.85).aspx or Intel MPI (paid): http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mpi-library.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - that's probably a good idea, but I thought MS-MPI was largely based on MPICH/MPICH2. I did a little poking around  regarding MS-MPI, and one of the differences with MPICH appears to be the security model, although I am at all sure about the details, which may explain a difference in Windows 7 vs Windows 8 behavior.  Anyway, thanks for pointing me in this direction.

Comment: You're right. MS-MPI is a derivative of MPICH, but they do make tweaks to actually get it running in Windows. As to the security model (or really any other specifics about MS-MPI), I don't know much about their implementation to help you much there.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue when using Windows 8. I tried turning to MS-MPI, but I found that it does not implement the spawn function, which I had used in my program.

My solution was to downgrade to Windows 7.